# Dropbox V2 Http API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the V2 Http API : https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation
I'm trying to post for: https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_metadata   for the root folder.

my request body: `{"path":""}`

my headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer my_token
Dropbox-API-Select-User: dbmid:some_user_id
```

I'm getting a response code 400 with the body:

```
Error in call to API function "files/get_metadata":
request body: path: '' did not match pattern '((/|id:).*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})'
```

sending an empty json didnt work too.

When I'm trying to get to a folder that's not root, it works (like : "/111").

In the documentation in the "Path formats" section it says : "The empty string ("") represents the root folder".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using "./" or "/" or ".".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. didn't work. still doesn't match the regex

Comment: Well it was worth a shot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that the root path should be indicated by the empty string "", however the [/files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata) endpoint doesn't support querying on the root, since there isn't any metadata to return for it anyway.

As you mentioned, and as you can see in the documentation, for any non-root folder, the path can be specified like "/Homework/math". The documentation also shows examples of specifying via id, like "id:a4ayc_80_OEAAAAAAAAAYa", or rev, like "rev:a1c10ce0dd78". The regex in the error message reflects those three options.

If your actual goal is to list the contents of root, you should instead use [/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder), which does allow the root path.